# How do I reorder the jobs on my Hudson dashboard?

Tags: hudson, dashboard

I have a number of jobs on my Hudson dashboard.  But they aren't in the order that I'd like them to be -- they are all jumbled relative to the order that they run and that I'd like to see them.  They appear to be in alphabetical order by default, but I don't want that.

How can I reorder them to my liking?  I don't want to have to force the issue by giving them numbers, letters at the start, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can. Hudson just sorts jobs based on their names.

You can create your own views, though, and use them to group your jobs. These views, however, are listed in alphabetical order, too.

Comment: Bummer -- that seems to be the case after digging around.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nick: About two years ago I went to the hudson mailing list and found a thriving community including the quite responsive Kohsuke Kawaguch himself. You might want to bring this up there.

Comment: As a side note, the means of ordering the jobs differently isnt even allowed through a plugin.  The comparator is hardcoded when starting hudson

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the column headers and sort by Status, Last Failure, etc.

It's not a great solution though, since that preference isn't persisted anywhere and there is no URL you can use to automatically get it.